# Which countries DO NOT have airports or airline services

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, airports, international-travel, airlines

I am curious to know the list of countries in the world which do not have air transport or airlines of their own .
My first assumption would be Vatican City as it is the smallest country of the would and will depend on other neighbouring countries for its air line services .

Would like to know other countries for the same .

EDIT : To be specific commercial airlines which let passengers in and out , it could be helipad also .

Comment: But Vatican City actually does have a field and the pope keeps a helicopter there. It's a VIP heliport but blows your question into 'unclear', please fix.

Comment: There are a few isolated islands which have nothing in the way of airports. Many small nations like Monaco manage to fit in a public-use helipad or two.

Comment: Also yachts in Monaco's harbour that have helipads...

Comment: Why is this being voted as "too broad"?  I'd be surprised if there are more than 10 UN-recognized countries that qualify.

Comment: I think the helipad bit makes the question a lot more broad. I would suggest to take it out. (I will not edit it myself as I feel it does change the question quite a bit.)

Comment: This question is perfectly relevant and perfectly understandable and should not have been put on hold.  OP is specifically asking about commercial air service which would include helicopters, and airships.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming "air services" means scheduled flights and not just chartered helicopters etc, off the top of my head we have:

- **Andorra**.  Nearest airport in Spain (Barcelona).
- **Liechtenstein**.  Nearest airport in Switzerland.
- **Monaco**.  Nearest airport in France.
- **San Marino**.  Nearest airport in Italy.
- **Vatican City**.  Nearest airport in Italy (Rome).

I believe that may actually be it, since (AFAIK) all Pacific, Caribbean and African microstates do have airports.  There are some territories like Pitcairn and St. Helena that don't, but none are independent.

**Palestine** may also qualify if you consider it a country, since all airports in Gaza and the West Bank have long been non-operational.

Edit: And of course it's already on Wikipedia! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_without_an_airport

Comment: Monaco has scheduled helicopter flights to Nice.

Comment: But are Monaco, San Marino, etc truly "countries"?

Comment: @Tom: Yes -- at least by most definitions I can think of. They are considered sovereign states in international law, issue passports recognized around the globe, conclude treaties and maintain diplomatic relations with other states in their own right, and are members of the UN and many other international organizations.

Comment: HLE on St. Helena opened last year.  Quick, edit before someone give you an unwarranted downvote!

Comment: But no scheduled flights to St Helena yet. And its not a separate country anyway.

Comment: Nice, although technically the airport closest to Andorra (at least from the Spanish) should be the one at Girona/Gerona, although it has far less connections availabre than Barcelona.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lleida%E2%80%93Alguaire_Airport

Comment: @Johns-305: HLE is a joke, not an airport. First they built it, then they decided conditions were too windy to use it. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Helena_Airport) for a good laugh.